# Host Laravel project in web hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to host my laravel project in my web hosting.

In my web hosting, there is `Public_html` folder. Before Laravel, I could call my website by using `default.php` or `index.php` in `Public_html` folder. But in laravel framework, `index.php` is in the `public` folder.

How can I access `Laravel/public/index.php` from my `Public_html`?

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) is a good start.

Comment: Thanks... @Alphonsus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a shared hosting you're using if yes then :

Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (be aware of don't overwrite the .htaccess file accidentally) then modify your index.php and your bootstrap.php and it will work just fine

Comment: Ok bro, Noted with Thanks.

Comment: This is the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

2 Options:

1. create index.php in Public_html which includes your original index.php
2. if possible change the document root in your .htaccess or in your virtual host config

Either way you should be aware of the fact, that everything in your Public_html will be visible to every user. So putting your business logic there is not a good idea. Hidden files can be set with .htaccess or if you place them outside of your document root. If you have no possibility to change it you should probably think about a virtual server.

Comment: Yes bro, that makes sense. Really Thanks for your Detail Answer. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

When I do a fresh installation of Laravel project on my localhost, I cut the **.htaccess file** from a public directory and paste(replace) it in the root of Laravel directory.

And I rename the **server.php file** in the root of Laravel directory to **index.php**

This way I eliminate the need for entering **public** word from the website URL.

Now in public_html, I paste the all files and folders from Laravel directory. 
This way when you type in your domain name then your website is loaded directly without showing your *public/index.php* inside the URL.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is contact support and kindly ask them to set to document root to `home/{domian}/{laravel-project-folder}/public` instead of `home/{domain]/public_html`. some hosts even allow you to set your own document root. some other need you to contact them.

I just came back from doing one such thing and it all worked. (after setting the correct write permissions on required folders inside the project folder. see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation)

doing so allowed me to have a production experience identical to my local experience.

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel you have the option (unless disabled by host) to set the public directory of a subdomain or addon domain.

I've done this in Laravel installations that are on addon domains,